# Convert embedded Neo4j 3.x (not 2.x) result to JSON (Java)

Tags: java, json, neo4j

I'm using embedded database for Neo4j, but lacks a convenient method to display result using JSON format when nodes or relationships (not properties) are being displayed.  There is a near solution for Neo4j 2.x, but not 3.x.

e.g. I want the node to display something like:

```
{"type":"Node", "labels":["User"], "properties":{"name": "Steve", "age": 300}}
```

without regard to what's inside the node. Is there a good way to do this?

**Maven Dependency for embedded neo4j 3.0.6**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

**Example code**

```
package TestCypher3b.TestCypher3b;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Result;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        GraphDatabaseFactory graphDbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
        final GraphDatabaseService  graphDb = graphDbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(new File("data/dbName"));


        List<String> queries = Arrays.asList(new String[]{
                "match (a) delete a;",
                "create (a:User {name:'Adam', age:100, children:['a','b','c']});",
                "create (a:User {name:'Eve', age:200, properties:[]});",
                "create (a:User {name:'Steve', age:300});",
        });

        queries.forEach(q -> {
            Result result = graphDb.execute(q);
            // System.out.println(result.resultAsString());
        });
        Result result = graphDb.execute("match (a) return a;");

        // String jsonOut = ...something like result.forEachRemaining(n -> toJson(n)...

        System.out.println(jsonOut);

    }
}
```

(FYI, Serializer like GSON and Jackson didn't work out of the box)

Comment: Your sample display isn't valid JSON; do you just want a string representation, or do you want a real JSON object with internal ID, labels, and properties?

Comment: Oh, you are right!  Yes, I guess that's not valid JSON - real JSON object is desirable, but if the solution is close enough, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN PROPERTIES(n);
```

The `PROPERTIES` function was added recently.

Comment: Result object contents needs to be converted to JSON string within Java, rather than modifying the Cypher query itself.  So after the result is retrieved, no cypher code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the source](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver/blob/1.1/driver/src/main/java/org/neo4j/driver/v1/types/Node.java) for the Node object in Java, you'll find all the info you need to get a full set of data for a Node: `Node.asMap()` for properties, `Node.labels()` for labels, and `Node.id()`for internal id are basically all there is to a Node, so you can build a JSON object to mimic that structure yourself fairly trivially. The `id` attribute used here is, again, the internal one, so you can't rely on it for long-term use, but it is going to be unique in a given result set (so you can use it as a Map key to track Nodes, e.g.).